# project delivery to a remote computer using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I configured MSbuild for delivery at iis. in the same MSbuild.xml I setup for delivery 4 more programs. Now everything works: TeamCity launches MSbuild.xml 
which creates 5 projects on the same computer. After one application delivered on iis server that is on another computer. I need another app comes to another computer, but not on iis but simply to a specific folder.

then the build project, which I want to put on a remote computer instead "OutDir=%(BuildArtifactsDir.FullPath)\DBUpgrader\

```
<MSBuild Projects="DatabaseUpgrader\DatabaseUpgrader\DatabaseUpgrader.sln"
             Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifactsDir.FullPath)\DBUpgrader\;Configuration=$(Configuration)"
             ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

did not quite understand (((could describe in detail or example? I have all the artifacts are added to the folder c: \ artefacts in this folder for example 2 project c: \ artefacts \ proj1 and c: \ artefacts \ proj2. I need to copy from c : \ artefacts \ proj2 all such files to the server \ \ 10.77.0.3 \ Proj2 where Proj2 a folder which has a share. if I perform

Program Files (x86) \ IIS \ Microsoft Web Deploy V3 \ msdeploy.exe-verb: sync-source: contentPath = c: \ artefacts \ proj2, includeAcls = true-dest: contentPath = \ \ 10.77.0.3 \ Proj2 then I all copied. but if I write so in msbuild

```
<MSBuild Projects="artefacts \proj2\proj2.sln"
             Properties="OutDir=\ \ 10.77.0.3 \С$\ Proj2;
             Configuration=$(Configuration); "
             ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

system writes that there is no permission to write to \ \ 10.77.0.3 \С$\ Proj2

Answer (score 0):

You can either build (or copy after build) to a UNC path or a share, e.g. `<MSBuild Properties="OutputPath=\\Foo\C$\Bar"` or use `msdeploy` with [`dirPath` provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207412.aspx) as it sounds like you already use it for IIS deployment.

Comment: made the first option. but the system says it can not access the \ \ Foo \ C $ \ DBUpdater though I gave all the right folder

Comment: @user3686190 `C$` is what's called an admin share (`C:` drive), so the service account that build agent is running under needs to be an admin the *Foo* server and admin shares need not be disabled. Otherwise create a normal Windows share on the server and give it appropriate permissions for your service user, i.e. `\\Foo\Bar`.

Comment: I added the question. please see